# cdburnerxp with cmd for converting bin

Tags: batch

trying to convert bin to an iso with cdburnerxp and keep getting an error. this is my command

```
FOR /r %%i IN (*.bin) DO ("D:\Downloads\CDBurnerXP-x64-4.5.8.7128\cdbxpcmd.exe" --burn-iso -file:"%%~dpnxi" -iso:"%%~dpni.iso")
```

which gives this

```
E:\PS2\error>FOR /R %i IN (*.bin) DO ("D:\Downloads\CDBurnerXP-x64-4.5.8.7128\cdbxpcmd.exe" --burn-iso -file:"%~dpnxi" -iso:"%~dpni.iso" )

E:\PS2\error>("D:\Downloads\CDBurnerXP-x64-4.5.8.7128\cdbxpcmd.exe" --burn-iso -file:"E:\PS2\error\Dynasty Warriors 2 (USA)\Dynasty Warriors 2 (USA).bin" -iso:"E:\PS2\error\Dynasty Warriors 2 (USA)\Dynasty Warriors 2 (USA).iso" )
Starting to burn ISO image from E:\PS2\error\Dynasty Warriors 2 (USA)\Dynasty Warriors 2 (USA).bin...
An error (8004027C) occured while executing the command: Device is not ready:
```

this is possible through the gui but i cant get cmd to work.

Comment: Try without brackets/parenthesis in the file name? Is there enough space on `E:\`?

Comment: same result device ```An error (8004027C) occured while executing the command: Device is not ready:```

Comment: and yes there is plenty space on E: